# Application.Exit() не закрывает приложение

Tags: c#

Есть поток, который выполняется бесконечно:

```
while(true)
```

В Form_Closing указал:

```
myThread.Abort();
if (web != null)
{
    web.Quit();
}
```

Selenium запускается ещё в:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

В потоке иногда возникает ситуация, что надо закрыть приложение и Selenium с окном браузера. Application.Exit(), Environment.Exit(0); не справляются с этой задачей. Поток останавливается, но окна не закрываются. В чём может быть проблема? Form_Closing срабатывает **безупречно** при нажатии на крестик Form1

Comment: В том, что они - отдельный самостоятельный процесс.

Comment: @Qwertiy Form_Closing срабатывает при клике на крестик Form1.  И закрываются все окна. А Application.Exit(), Environment.Exit(0) не закрывают даже Form1

Comment: @VladislavSokolov `Environment.Exit(0)` должен. Если не работает, значит что-то не так. Вероятно, комментарий Qwertiy указывает верное направление

Comment: @VladislavSokolov , можно ещё `Form.Close()` попробовать. Если это главное окно программы, то она завершит работу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я изначально завершал мой процесс перед закрытием программы.
Помогло банальное:

```
        Form1 form = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;
        form.Close();
```

Оно же и вызывало Form_Closing.